# How to copy the content of a file using command line

Tags: command-line, scripts, copy, cat, copy-and-paste

My question is may be too simple or hard

Is there any way I can copy the content of a file using the command line
the same as you do with right click + copy?
After that I want to paste what I copied somewhere else, but without creating a new file or use `>` redirections like `cat file1 > file2`.

Answer (score 2):

What you actually want is to copy strings from a file or command output (or any other output) to the clipboard.
In windows powershell scripting you have built in clipboard commands, including such syntax: `"some_variable_or_output" |clip`.

You can do the same in ubuntu using xclip, but you may need to install this package first. The syntax would be `cat file | xclip` or `some_output | xclip`. 
To paste your clipboard content you'll need to use `xclip -o` with additional parameters depending on where you want to redirect this output.

If needed, install the package using `sudo apt-get install xclip`.

Comment: Thank you for you answer , to explain more , i'm connecting to a server , i need to work on some files on my computer that's why i need ro tranform them to my computer by copying the content , thats why i need a command that work exactly like click rigth + copy ( i don't know if there's any other way ) i can't not use  sudi do download xclip  because i'm just simple user , Thank you .

Comment: How exactly are you connecting to that server? Are all your commands executed on the server environment? Do you share the server's clipboard with your own computer?

Comment: im connected to the server as normal user , i can't run sudo command

Comment: I mean what method of remote connection are you using? SSH? You have your personal computer and a server, how do you communicate with it? Many protocols and programs offer shared clipboard. In that case you can take the content, refine whatever you need and copy it to your local clipboard. After that redirect it to wherever you need.

Comment: Ahhh yes im using SSH  remote connection , sorry i didn't know what you mean before

Comment: Okay, so in general as I said, SSH connections usually share their clipboards between the client and the server. Your problem is that you can't copy anything to the clipboard on the server because you can't install xclip, BUT you can install it on your client. So here is a nice trick for you assuming you can also ssh from the server to your local client and a connection is already open: `<command> | ssh user@your_client "cat > output.txt"`, or in your case: `<command> | ssh user@your_client "|xclip"`. This will perform a command on the server, send the output via SSH and pipe it to your clip.

Comment: Hello , please i didn't undrestand your proposition too much , user@your_client : is that the name of my personal computer ( where i'm connected now ) or the name of my account on the server , and also i want to ask if this command will work for me , scp -r -p user@serveur1:chemin/vers/dossier/source user@serveur2:chemin/vers/dossier/destination ?? thanks a lot

Comment: Sometimes you would like to execute a quick single command on a remote destination without actually opening an ssh shell in a new window / terminal. This can be done in a single line: `ssh <user>@<remote_host> "your_command_on_remote_host"`. You can also pipe a command output from your local host to a remote host, and add a command to be executed there with your piped output:  `<local_command> | ssh <user>@<remote_host> "some_command_like_cat_to_handle_your_piped_string"`.

Comment: So if you are already connected to the remote server via SSH, do your needed operation on it, and in a single line command SSH the output back to your personal computer and in the remote command section use `"|xclip"`. This will save whatever content you needed from the server in your personal computer's clipboard. For example: assuming you're connected to the server: `cat file_on_server | ssh personal_computer_user@personal_computer_ip "|xclip"`. This should do the trick.

Comment: And if i want to copy the whole folder from server to my personal computer ( actually i have more than 30 file so it ll be little bit dificult to do that 30 times ..

Comment: Then it is not as you described in your question - just copy the files physically using scp command or FTP services.